# How to access funds from a fork?

Tags: private-key, public-key

So I want to access funds from various bitcoin forks, and I have my keys.

Are there any sites, or services that allows me to enter my keys to get access to the funds from the forks?

Point me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to download a wallet that supports the said fork.

So for example for the "Bitcoin Cash" fork, you will need to download something like this, https://electroncash.org/

Take extreme care when downloading these wallets, as a lot of them are infected/and or malware.

Always check the authenticity of the wallet files you download.

For electronCash they can be found here https://github.com/fyookball/keys-n-hashes

Comment: So then I will be able to input my key into the wallets and have access to the funds?

Comment: Yes, import the private keys which held bitcoin at the time of the (in this case bitcoin cash) snapshot, and your bitcoin cash should be there. (Check if your adress has balance in a bitcoin cash blockexplorer such as https://blockchair.com/bitcoin-cash/blocks)

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's time to check the balances and fire up the VM and see what works